# Variation (how many do I Need)?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm creating bingo cards for Rock and Roll Bingo and am trying to work out whether I have enough variants.

Each Bingo card has 16 answers printed on it, randomised from a possible 24 answers, using a formula in Excel.

I want to create 100 cards and am trying to work out whether I have enough variants for them each to be unique.  Please help, I'd be very grateful.

Regards, Pete

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking, but $\binom {24}{16}=735,471$ so you could make that many unique cards.  Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Please read tag descriptions.

Comment: This does not sound like Bingo at all, which deals with selecting numbers that might be in rows.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see here, as it isn't particularly clear as to what you are asking. If I am answering something you are not asking, then please feel free to comment below and explain.

I am assuming the cards are written in a $4 \times 4$ style without a "Free" space, as that will be able to fit the desired $16$ different answers onto one card.

As lulu already mentioned in the comments, we have $735,471$ bingo cards with different combinations of the $24$ possible answers. And that isn't even including the orientation of each of those possible combinations. (In fact if we did include orientation we would be talking over $15 \text{ quintillion}$ possible cards).

So maybe you mean to ask if $24$ possible answers on a $4 \times 4$ card is enough to make $100$ unique bingo cards. If that is the case, then the answer is **yes**.